# Chrome 29 Style/Css issues

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, google-chrome

I’m having this issue with Chrome Canary (version 29.0.1521.0) and also the Dev Channel.

Basically, I have a page with a separate style sheet for printing. In Chrome 26, 27, 28, and any other browser (including Firefox Nightly), my page is displayed correctly. However, since Canary and Dev channel upgraded to version 29, I get the print styles applied to the page, with no way to get the normal styles back. It is definitely a JavaScript problem, not CSS, you can even see the correct page loaded for a split second before it is hidden by the print style sheet. CSS Media overrides do nothing, and there are no JavaScript errors or warnings, except occasionally the tab will hang and become unresponsive, using 100% of a CPU core. When the tab hangs, all Dev tools are unresponsive and cannot be used.

There are a couple of ways I’ve found to circumvent the problem: for example, killing the tab and refreshing it (even when it is not hanging) will usually load the page correctly, for a couple of page loads. Disabling JavaScript also fixes the problem (not practical). When the page loads correctly all the elements are functional and correctly displayed.

I have searched the net for people having similar issues and haven’t come up with anything.

Does Anyone know if there is anything i can do to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, its not guaranteed to work correctly at all, working around it seems a waste of time given the update frequency/moving target nature of the thing. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244495

Comment: Hey there, Perfect answer, not sure why i couldn't find that when i was looking! (Maybe you're a better googler than me ;) )

Did you want to put that as a response rather than a comment and i'll mark as answer?

Comment: (Sounds like version 29 of Chrome is 'on the Blink'. Ahem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, its not guaranteed to work correctly at all, working around it seems a waste of time given the update frequency/moving target nature of the thing.

Here is what seems to be the existing bug report: [CSS loaded from cache with different media as screen is loaded as screen](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244495).