# Chrome is applying the print stylesheet to screen, while IE, FF, Safari are working correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome

My bank website stops working in Chrome because the top and side menus and buttons are made hidden with the CSS rule:

```
hr, #date, #logout, #navigation, ul.sectionLink, p.submit, #sideContent, #footer {
display: none;
}
```

However, that is defined in the print.css stylesheet and not to be applied to screen:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/maybank_css/screen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/maybank_css/print.css">
```

What can cause Chrome to apply a print stylesheet to screen? [image: Screenshot with Developer Tool]

Chrome Version 29.0.1521.3 dev-m.

Comment: Check my reply, should help. Have made this mistake MANY times myself.

Answer (score 4):

This is not the default behavior in Chrome.

If I were to guess, I'd say you have [a plugin installed](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) (it's the cog) for debugging print stylesheets and haven't disabled the option to show them.

Click the Web Developer plugin > CSS tab > Disable Print Styles.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not remember any plugin that can cause this. Anyway, to be completely sure, I removed all plugins, cleared all cache, restarted Chrome, and it's the same.

Comment: I solved it by uninstalling Chrome and install a non-developer version, now it works correctly. So, it is probably some plugin that caused the behavior. +1 for the answer.

Comment: Hmm that's strange, I'm using Chrome Canary and don't see that behavior. :o

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with Chrome since version 29. See:

- [Chrome 29 Style/Css issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815834/chrome-29-style-css-issues)
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244090

The temporary fix is to wrap the print stylesheet in a `@media` rule like this:

```
@media print {
   /* your CSS here */
}
```